# Tables relationship logic

Tags: database, logic

I have a logic question, I have two tables, Doctor and Specialty, and I don´t know who belong to who. Doctors can have more than one specialty, but I´m not sure how to set it up.

A doctor can have multiple specializations, so my logic says that a table named specialty should belong to a table doctor. Does this makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have all the doctors in one table, say `Doctor` and all specialties in another table `Specialty`. Then you should have a linking table that contains the list of specialties for a given doctor.

- Doctor

  - DoctorId
  - Name
  - Degree etc.,
- Specialty

  - SpecialtyId
  - Name etc.,
- SpecializedDoctors

  - SpecialtyId
  - DoctorId

This would help you identify the specialties of a doctor or doctors with a specialty.